# send java object as parameter in birt and use it in query

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, birt

I'm new to birt reporting tool and my goal is to send java object as parameter and use it in the `Query` in `Data Sets`.

> example: say i have an object of type user that have
>   (id,name,email...) so in my query i use it like "user.id" ...

I am calling birt report using report engine :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/birtReport1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ApiOperation("Download Report")
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        //get report name and launch the engine
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
//      resp.setContentType( "application/pdf" ); 
        //resp.setHeader ("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=test.pdf");       
        String reportName = "/Documents/workspace/Birt/MyFirstReport.rptdesign";
        ServletContext sc = req.getSession().getServletContext();
        this.birtReportEngine = BirtEngine.getBirtEngine(sc);
        IReportRunnable design;
        try
        {
            //Open report design
            design = birtReportEngine.openReportDesign( reportName );
            //create task to run and render report
            IRunAndRenderTask task = 
            birtReportEngine.createRunAndRenderTask( design );      
            String[] values = {"10096", "10094"};
            task.setParameterValue("idCatalogue",values);
            HTMLRenderOption options = new HTMLRenderOption();
        options.setOutputFormat(HTMLRenderOption.OUTPUT_FORMAT_HTML);
            options.setOutputStream(resp.getOutputStream());
            task.setRenderOption(options);

            //run report
            task.run();
            task.close();
        }catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ServletException( e );
        }
    }
```

how can i do this?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You are already setting parameters. Is it working? what error are you facing?

Comment: @Simulant thank you for your reply , i managed to solve it by using javascript inside the report but now i'm facing a problem with embedded image ,glad if you can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49530934/birt-embedded-image-doesnt-work-in-html-format